# Background color in indicator when conditions are met

Tags: pine-script, background-color, trading, pine-script-v5

I have been trying to add background colors when certain conditions are met in this indicator that combines Walter Bresserts double stochastic and the RSI.

I want the background color to turn green when "long" conditions are met and red when "short" conditions are met:

long = ((rsi < 15 or rsi[1] < 15 or rsi[2] < 15) and (dds10 < 25))

short = ((rsi > 85 or rsi[1] > 85 or rsi[2] > 85) and (dds10 > 85))

Does anyone here know how to do that?

Thanks in advance,
Philip

```
//@version=5
indicator('RSI & DT Bressert')
HighlightBreaches = input(true, title='Highlight Oversold/Overbought?')
period = input.int(defval=13, title='Period', minval=1, maxval=16)
top = 85
bot = 25

len = input.int(2, minval=1, title='Length')
src = input(close, 'Source')
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)
plot(rsi, 'RSI', color=color.new(#C0C0C0, 0))

period10 = input(title='Periodes', defval=10)
period5 = input(title='Periodes', defval=5)

stochastic10 = ta.ema((close - ta.lowest(low, period10)) / (ta.highest(high, period10) - ta.lowest(low, period10)) * 100, 3)
dds10 = ta.ema((stochastic10 - ta.lowest(stochastic10, period10)) / (ta.highest(stochastic10, period10) - ta.lowest(stochastic10, period10)) * 100, 3)

stochastic5 = ta.ema((close - ta.lowest(low, period5)) / (ta.highest(high, period5) - ta.lowest(low, period5)) * 100, 3)
dds5 = ta.ema((stochastic5 - ta.lowest(stochastic5, period5)) / (ta.highest(stochastic5, period5) - ta.lowest(stochastic5, period5)) * 100, 3)

hline(title='OB', price=top, color=color.black)
hline(title='OS', price=bot, color=color.black)

plot(series=dds10, color=dds10[1] < dds10 ? color.green : color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(series=dds5, color=dds5[1] < dds5 ? color.blue : color.navy, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this at the end of your code. It uses [bgcolor()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_bgcolor)

```
long = ((rsi < 15 or rsi[1] < 15 or rsi[2] < 15) and (dds10 < 25))
short = ((rsi > 85 or rsi[1] > 85 or rsi[2] > 85) and (dds10 > 85))
bgcolor(long ? color.green : short ? color.red : na)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This creates exactly what I wanted!